# How is the "__ARM_common_switch8 PROC" produced in Keil uVision4

Tags: assembly, arm

I wrote a c program including a `switch` statement:

```c
int main(){
  char* i;
  int j;
  for(j=0;j<9;j++){
    switch(j){
        case 0: i[j]='a';break;
        case 1: i[j]='s';break;
        case 2: i[j]='s';break;
        case 3: i[j]='e';break;
        case 4: i[j]='m';break;
        case 5: i[j]='b';break;
        case 6: i[j]='l';break;
        default:i[j]='y';break;
      } 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When compile it with keil uVision4, I found a new function named `__ARM_common_switch8` in the assembly file：

```
__ARM_common_switch8 PROC
    PUSH     {r4,r5}
    MOV      r4,lr
    SUBS     r4,r4,#1
    LDRB     r5,[r4,#0]
    ADDS     r4,r4,#1
    CMP      r3,r5
    BCC      |L13.24|
|L13.14|
    LDRB     r3,[r4,r5]
    LSLS     r3,r3,#1
    ADDS     r3,r4,r3
    POP      {r4,r5}
    BX       r3
|L13.24|
    MOV      r5,r3
    B        |L13.14|
    ENDP
```

and the main PROC is as follows:

```
main PROC
    PUSH     {lr}
    MOVS     r1,#0
    B        |L1.74|
|L1.6|
    MOVS     r3,r1
    BL       __ARM_common_switch8
    DCB      0x07,0x05,0x08,0x0b
    DCB      0x0e,0x11,0x14,0x17
    DCB      0x1a,0x00
    MOVS     r0,#0x61
    STRB     r0,[r2,r1]
    B        |L1.70|
    MOVS     r0,#0x63
    STRB     r0,[r2,r1]
    B        |L1.70|
    MOVS     r0,#0x63
    STRB     r0,[r2,r1]
    B        |L1.70|
    MOVS     r0,#0x65
    STRB     r0,[r2,r1]
    B        |L1.70|
    MOVS     r0,#0x73
    STRB     r0,[r2,r1]
    B        |L1.70|
    MOVS     r0,#0x73
    STRB     r0,[r2,r1]
    B        |L1.70|
    MOVS     r0,#0x77
    STRB     r0,[r2,r1]
    B        |L1.70|
    MOVS     r0,#0x71
    STRB     r0,[r2,r1]
    NOP      
|L1.70|
    NOP      
    ADDS     r1,r1,#1
|L1.74|
    CMP      r1,#9
    BLT      |L1.6|
    MOVS     r0,#0
    POP      {pc}
    ENDP
```

How is the `__ARM_common_switch8 PROC` produced? Can the compiler produce a new function? And by the way, with optimization set to level O1/O2/O3, this function will disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I met this problem once in my experiment. Then I found when you use more than 7 switch-cases, compile would call this library function-'ARM_COMMON_SWITCH8' to help compute the address that program would switch to.

As far as I know, there are two methods to solve this problem. One is dividing your switch structure into several smaller 'condition structure' such as 'if and else' and switch structure with less than 6 cases. The second method is using optimization options such as '-O1,-O2,-O3,-Os'.